# "Left" and "right" are to "side" as "front" and "rear" are to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, analogy

Is there an equivalent word to "side" when speaking of the front or rear of something (e.g. a car)?

So, a mechanic might say:

> You damaged your wing-mirror? Ok, which **side**?

... or...

> You damaged your bumper? Ok, which [insert word here]?

Comment: Technically, *side* can include front, back, top, bottom, and more depending on how many *sides* an object has.

Comment: Related: [Is there a word like “sides” that means “top or bottom”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84055/is-there-a-word-like-sides-that-means-top-or-bottom)

Comment: "You damaged your bumper? Ok, which one?" is usually how I would say it.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: That would be the *forebumper* or the *afterbumper* of course.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**End**

Like "two ends of a stick"?

Comment: "Top end" and "bottom end" often refer ranges, or qualities. Also, the "top end" of Australia in the northern Northern Territory. I don't think end is exclusive to, or even implies, front/back, except in limited circumstances. Also, which end of a stick is the front?

Comment: @naught101: Usually, ends refer to the further edges of an elongated shape and sides refer to the nearer ones. If something stands sideways to you, you can talk about left and right end. Also, a painting on the wall has the front and rear side.

Comment: Exactly, *end* is not to front/rear as *side* is to left/right. It just happens to be in the particular instance provided as an example. The front and rear of the wall are not "ends".

Comment: (s/wall/painting/). To back your argument though, "end" is also [used in biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_%28anatomy%29#Anterior_and_posterior).

Comment: When I hear "end" in relation to a car's bumpers, I still think left or right - as each bumper individually has 2 ends.  Although if somebody said they'd damaged their bumper, I might still say "which side?" because bumpers are implicitly at the front and back of a car, which are still technically "sides".  It gets a little hairier when you say e.g. "I damaged my tire car's tire" - because then you have to indicate both.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. People routinely talk about the "front end" and the "rear end" of a car. I've never heard someone say "the front side" of a car. Yes, a flat object like a painting or a sheet of paper is typically said to have a "front side" and a "rear side". So what? In the other dimensions we talk about the "edges" of a small flat object. But if you have a long piece of a flat object, e.g. a roll of paper or cloth, we talk about the "ends" of the roll as a dimension perpendicular to "sides" along the long axis.

Comment: *Car* is an example is OP's question. *End* inherently suggests one of an elongated object only. Though correct in this case, *end* may not suit as a generic answer for the question.

Comment: -1 Why only "**two** ends of a stick"? What about all (any of) the other? Ergo, *end* cannot be used for a generic unknown facet of the object. Check the Q. once again: "which [insert word here]". We need a word that suits left, right, front, rear, top, bottom, (more if applicable).

Comment: @Kris: As others correctly noted, neither "end" nor "side" is bound to either "left" or "front". But whenever you're talking about an edge which is not a side, you're talking about an end. So if it has left and right side, it will have front and rear end, and vice versa. Unless it's all sides.

Comment: People routinely talk about their "front end bumper" or "back end bumper". Google it. `End` is obviously the right answer.

Answer (score 33):

In terms of [anatomical locations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location#Anterior_and_posterior), front (anterior) and rear (posterior) are on the anteroposterior axis.

So you could say "Which [end](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87179/20482) of the Anteroposterior axis?" This is obviously ludicrous, but might be OK if your customer was an MD or biologist. 
[image]

Comment: lol. Why is there a fish on my screen?

Comment: -1 Sorry, here *end* refers to a pointed termination with respect to the body, considering  the AP-axis. Note that we are not using *end* in a generic sense for an **unknown** facet -- Dorsal **side**, Ventral **side**. Check out the question one more time: "which [insert word here]".

Comment: @Kris Thanks for explaining your down-vote. Not sure I follow you. Wing mirrors are lateral (left, right) and bumpers are at the ends of the AP-axis, at least on every car I've seen. Cars and fish have a front (as opposed to trees).

Comment: Precisely. We don't use *end* when referring to the group (left, right, front, back) in a general way -- only with reference to front and back. OP needs a word where we do not know if it is the left, right, front or back. According to your own answer, "which end" asks only if *front* or *back* and precludes *left* and *right*. *Side* by definition is inclusive.

Comment: I understand your technical interpretation, but it's not how I saw the OP's question. There are some definitions of *side*, e.g., the first definition here of [side](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/side) that are only left and right.

Comment: This only works with certain fish, however. Flounders present a problem.

Comment: @JohnLawler Unless you kill them and make fish sticks of them. Of course, you need to make sure that the form of the fish stick is... hmm... "sticky"... (Also, +1 for the fish.)

Comment: @Kris: Actually, I think it's you who needs to read the question again. The OP specifically *does* want a word which refers to front/back but precludes left/right.

Comment: Wish I could +1 this several times. Best answer I've seen on English SE in a while.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so. You'd probably get 'front or back' again from some people, or just 'one' as in context, you've only got two bumpers, front and back.

> You damaged your bumper? Ok, which one?

Comment: +1 wing mirrors are implicitly on left-rigth sides, whereas bumpers  are implicitly on front-back sides.

Comment: Unless you're driving a dodgem!

Answer (score 7):

Technically, *side* can include front, back, top, bottom, and more depending on how many *sides* an object has.

[side](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/side) noun
1. one of the surfaces forming the outside of or bounding a thing, or one of the lines bounding a geometric figure.

[side](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/side)
3 b : a line or surface forming a border or face of an object

---

[EDIT]
The import of this answer is that *side* is **not** incorrect, and as such we need look no further in the first place. I do not necessarily disagree with other answers, other than that they are oblivious to this fact.

The question is based on the presumption that *side* excludes *front* and *rear*, which I contradict here.

Answer (score 3):

*Front-side, back-side, left-side, right-side, top-side* and *bottom-side* are all perfectly acceptable English terms. I agree that the question "Which side, front or back?" does sound a little strange, though.

Comment: +1 Not always strange though - e.g. side of an album cover (front/back)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in the English language other than having been brought up with it. Add salt for taste.

That said one term I have seen used frequently in terms of front and rear is *facing*. "What is the object's front facing? What is the object's rear facing?" It sets up a nice set of useful mathematical concepts where a transverse line across the front facing of an object demarks all the things in front of the object. Same with the rear. It is also possible to describe what is in front on smaller arcs if the object has some depth. This leads to understanding what is to the sides of an object as well. Slice it up as many ways as you want for the utility you need in describing the object in relation to other things.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you're talking about. Anything with a left and a right side requires either an object with a front and back, or an orientation derived from an observer.

Trees, for instance, have no front or back and therefore no left or right, except as oriented by where the speaker and/or listener are standing with respect to the tree.

- *??Find the lone pine tree and dig on the right side.*
- *Walk north to the lone pine tree and dig on the right side.*

For more, see the [Space](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf) lecture, from Fillmore's 1971 [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).