# "Place the television on/in the left corner and sofa set at/in the right corner"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in, in-on

One question came in my exam:

> We've decided to place the television *on/in* the left corner and sofa set *at/in* the right corner of the room.

For non-livings there should be a common preposition. Unfortunately, I have two English teachers and their answers contradict. One says in both cases *in* should be used, and the other says for television it's *on*.

Could anybody explain?

Comment: What did you put in your exam answer, and why?

Comment: Why did you say "in", and what reason was given for that being wrong?

Comment: Hmm. You've now asked three questions in quick succession about *on* versus *in*. Does [this reference](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-place.htm) help? Or [this one](http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/in_on_at.html)? They may not be the best but both indicate a difference between *in* and *on*. *In the corner* and *at the corner* are slightly less clear-cut.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks a lot. My confusion is somehow disappearing among these.

Comment: There are two problems here. One is the [dimensionality of the metaphor](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299) -- locational _at_ or container _in_, which have different boundary conditions -- and the other is the [position of the observer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/87178/15299) for determining Left/Right orientation.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why would anyone think "preposition of location" is affected by whether it's an animate or inanimate subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All possible permutations of on/in/at, in both slots, are *grammatical* English sentences, but one choice ("in" for both) is the *convention* in my dialect.  I'm just going to discuss the part about the television; the logic is the same for the sofa set.

The central meaning of "in" is "inside": A gift is *in* a box.  For a noun to be *in* a corner, therefore, you should be talking about the concave side of the corner.  This is normally how we talk about the corner of a *room* in my dialect, so "in" is the natural choice for me for both the television and the sofa set.  *In* might also be how we talk about the corner of a building: The manager's office is *in* the northeast corner of building 12.  However, we might be talking about the outside of the building, and then you would use *at* instead: There is an oak tree *at* the northeast corner of building 12.

The central meaning of "on" is "stacked on top of".  It is difficult to imagine a situation where something could be stacked on top of the corner of a *room*, so "on" sounds very strange when you are talking about the position of objects within rooms.  But you would say that a dinner plate is *on* the corner of a table.  *On* is also used by convention when describing where buildings are relative to streets: Building 12 is *on* the corner of Route 19 and Tower Road.  This is perhaps because the building is, if only metaphorically, stacked on the ground at that location.

The central meaning of "at" is "located at a definite point in space".  It is not wrong to use "at the corner" for all of the above examples, but when a more specific spatial relationship applies (insideness, stacked-atop-ness, etc) English prefers that you use the more specific preposition.

The television and sofa set being inanimate objects is not important.  I cannot presently think of any *preposition* that cares whether the noun is animate.

---

Regarding one teacher saying that *on* should be used for a television relative to a corner of a room, I find that peculiar, but I can make up a *motivation* for saying it that way.  Normally you would not put a television directly on the floor; there would be a piece of furniture (a table, let's say) to raise the TV to a comfortable viewing height.  I would describe this situation as: the TV is *on* the table, but both the TV and the table are *in* the corner.  Your teacher may instead feel that only the table is *in* the corner, and because the TV is *on* the table it is also *on* the corner.  I would not be surprised to learn that this is a difference of dialect.

Comment: While a TV can be on the corner of a table, it can never be on the corner of a room.  Given the current context I think the teacher is in error. +1 for the rest of your answer.

Comment: @Jim I have been surprised so many times by dialectal differences ("Frequency of bus is very less" is apparently the *correct* way to say "Buses are very infrequent" in some registers of Indian English!) that I have given up on saying someone is *in error*.  I'll only go as far as "If you say that people will not understand what you mean," and "The TV is on the corner of the room" isn't even that bad.